# How to use new Google's Sans font in my Android App?

Tags: android, android-fonts, google-fonts

How can I use the font seen in fresh Google's apps like Phone, Contact and Google Fit in my Android App? Is there some new `textAppearance` value for this? Here's the preview of desired font (titles):
[image: Google's new material font]

As I could find out, this font is called something like "Google Sans".

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot (should not). It is not licensed to used by developers. It is used for Google's own branding. Even I'm tempted to use it, but I guess we'll have to hold that thought. Check this out https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18266

Answer (score -2):

I've also was wondering how to use it, for personal use though. Oddly enough I used this and it works perfectly fine, though I own a pixel device and am pretty sure this won't work on other devices. Here's what I used for the TextView:

```
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.Button"
```